# Azure API Management in consumption tier and Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

Does Azure API Management in consumption tier support integration with Azure AD B2C for end user authentication and authorization?

API Management pricing page indicates that in consumption tier, it does not support developer portal and Azure AD integration in developer portal, but doesn't specifically talk about Azure AD B2C.

Any details/ pointers appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes see this to setup APIM to be accessed via AAD B2C issuer tokens.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-api-management?tabs=app-reg-ga

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look at this.

Comment: But, this doesn't really answer the question:  does the consumption tier APIM support B2C integration as well ?